# Can i fetch data from url in Nodejs - Messenger BOT

Tags: node.js

Please help me fix this code
I have a Messenger Chat BOT (working), now i want to fetch data from message body url but this not working and give me 500 HTTP error! I use node-fetch and this is my Handle Message code, can u help me to fix it? Thanks!

```
function handleMessage(sender_psid, received_message) {
    let response;

    // Checks if the message contains text
    if (received_message.text) {
        switch (received_message.text.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').trim().toLowerCase()) {
            case "room preferences":
                response = setRoomPreferences(sender_psid);
                break;
            default:
                var address = received_message.text;
                var q = url.parse(address, true);
                if(q.host == null){
                    var nhan = 'Not detect url';
                }
                else {
// This code not working
var response = await fetch('url.com');
var body = await response.text();

var nhan = body;

                }
                response = {
                    "text": `${nhan}`
                };
                break;
        }
    } else {
        response = {
            "text": `Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.`
        }
    }

    // Send the response message
    callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed6wb.png)

Comment: How did you call `await` when you're not in Async function ? Also you wrote `url.com` when you should to add `http` or `https` at the first of your url check your code and edit it

Answer (score 0):

await should be called inside an async function. async function handleMessage...